# Can you identify this egg shaped pedestal

Tags: part-identification

Can you identify this white egg shaped pedestal? I've searched Bricklink for `egg` and `pedestal` and couldn't find it.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

You're looking at [part 24946 "Egg with small pin hole"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24946).

The bottom of the egg is hollow and accepts a stud, so your "pedestal" is nothing but a [1x1 plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3024).